# Bootstrap blue outline when modal is closed

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new at website programming and I'm currently using Bootstrap, but I'm struggling with a problem that I just can't fix.

I have a navbar where one of the links open a modal, but when the modal closes, then there is a blue outline around the link in the navbar.

is it possible to remove this blue box? I just can't find the styling, that causes it?

Comment: try `*:focus { outline: 0; }`

Comment: Please post a minimal, working example of your code (HTML/CSS/JS). See [mcve] and [ask].

Answer (score 0):

That blue outline exists for accessibility. It helps people navigate through the links and tabs. Most people would recommend that you don't remove it.

You haven't posted your code (a requirement on this website), so I don't know exactly which element needs styling, but this is the code you would add **to that element**:

```
:focus {
  outline: 0;
}
```

As Jdsfighter stated, you could also add this to your stylesheet to remove the outline from every element.

```
*:focus {
  outline: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone bump into this like I did. In Bootstrap >5 it's box-shadow:

```
:focus {
    box-shadow: none;
}
```